# Can we automate windows based mobile app in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to automate mobile based app. using selenium webdriver.
Can it be possible as it is possible for iOS and Android.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible

```
1.Obtain and install Windows Phone 8 SDK
2.You will need ISETool.exe which is a part of Windows Phone SDK and installed as its part
3.If you want to automate Windows Phone emulator, not a physical device - then you'll need 
  Windows Phone 8 emulator image, which can be obtained from Windows Phone SDK, or a Windows 
  Phone device.
4.Download our driver and unpack it anywhere on your local disk
5.Deploy WindowsPhoneDriver.xap to the phone! If you use emulator, just run StartWindowsPhoneDriver.cmd 
  and it will do everything for you, and prints the IP address/port to the console 
  (for example, "http://157.59.109.235:8080/"). It will also set system environment variable 
  REMOTEWEBDRIVERIP.
6.Use it from your code with RemoteWebDriver!
```

for more info click [here](http://winphonewebdriver.codeplex.com/)